# Android Studio context returning null

Tags: android, null, android-context

I have a class that's inputting some data into SharedPreferences.

```
private static Context context;

context = MainActivity.getContext();
sp = (SharedPreferences) context.getSharedPreferences("currentData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putString("name", placeName);
editor.apply()
```

I set the context using a method in my MainActivity class:

```
public static Context getContext(){
    return context;
}
```

However I keep getting a null object reference. Tried multiple solutions from stack overflow and can't overcome the issue.

Why is context returning null?

Answer (score 2):

You can get context statically throughout the application
please try below code:
In the Android Manifest file, declare the following.

```
 <application android:name="com.xyz.MyApplication">
    </application>
```

Use this class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static Context context;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyApplication.context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public static Context getAppContext() {
        return MyApplication.context;
    }
}
```

Now you can call MyApplication.getAppContext() to get your application context statically.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `MainActivity.getContext()` is `null` try passing the context *from* MainActivity to your class.

```
 public Context context;

 public YourClass(Context context) {
     this.context= context;
 }
```

In MainActivity init it like this:-

```
 YourClass yours = new YourClass(MainActivity.this);
```

And also *avoid* using **static contexts** it might cause *memory leaks* !!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the context from a static method in the class, that mean that method is called before the class is actually initialized. If there is no actual instance of the activity or if the OS haven't provide with context to the activity, then is null. The Activity has access to the contexto but after the Android underlining management initialized it, the class won't have the context by it self because it is there, if you notice Activities are never instantiated using the constructor because Android does it for you.

If you want to use a static method to having a nice syntax then the static method should be inside the class that use the shared preferences and should be passed from the activity, during any method of the Activity life cycle or when the user interacts with the ui (those listeners are set on the Activity life cycle).

```
class MyPreferences {
     static void save(String toSave, Contex context) {
            //TODO your operation here
     }
}
```

And your activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Below is pseudo code, be careful on doing this precisely in the activity
@Override
onCreate() {
    //TODO call super and setContentView
    MyPreferences.save("foo", this);
}
}
```

It seems your problem is you are trying to make the other class to use the Activity, but in Android is the Activity that uses other classes

Answer (score 1):

> Context is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the
>   Android system

Context is provided to any `Activity` by the android system during runtime (`Activity` indirectly extends `Context`). You are trying to get `Context` from `MainActivity` class via static method, which will not work and will always return `null`:

```
context = MainActivity.getContext();
```

You should always get `Context` from an instance of `Activity`, not the class itself. You can do this easily by passing an instance of your current Activity to the constructor of your class. Then, you call `getContext()` on an INSTANCE of that `Activity`, not the `Activity` class itself.

Also, wanted to mention that your code is mostly anti-pattern. You should never store Context in static variables. I'd recommend you read more about Activity lifecycle in android and Context - these are fundamental knowledge.

Comment: It seems the OP is trying to do every available work arround, while disregarding basic Android usage. Something to add is that Context is one of the most upper classes in Android framework and the main usage is to access resources, is very nice you point it has to be provided by the Android system https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Comment: @cutiko - I revised my answer once more, thank you for the support. Yeah, I added few lines about the fundamentals too.